# Intuitive understanding of CMS-Rights

Tags: usability, image, intuition, use-cases

I am working on a CMS and users have problems to understand the Rights. Every user registers automatically and have no right unless someone put him into a Rightgroup. A Rightgroup have 15 rights enabled or disabled.

[image]

The description is:

1. Add/Remove languages (often used by a webmaster).
2. Add/Remove/Configure menupoints (often used by a desinger, a webmaster).
3. Translate menupoints (often used by a translator).
4. Translate articles (often used by a translator).
5. Users in this group can log-in (used by a webmaster, an admin)
6. Create articles (often used by an contributing editor).
7. Enable/disable menupoints (often used by a lead translator).
8. Move articles up and down (often used by a translator).
9. Move menupoints up and down (often used by a webmaster).
10. Can paste a menupoint (often used by a webmaster).
11. Can cut a menupoint (often used by a webmaster).
12. unknown/not used.
13. Can modify a rightgroup (used by an admin).
14. Can put an user into a rightgroup (used by an admin).
15. Can flag an article to be on the landing-page (used by a webmaster).

I think the #1 is a good choice but #10/#11 is not.

What images should be used to give a intuitive understanding and avoid a translation of the description? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I'd rearrange the rights. Currently menupoints are in 2, 3, 7, 9, 10 and 11. That's kind of scattershot.

Second, have similar icons for similar tasks. None of the above mentioned icons have the same symbol reused for 'menupoint'. Is it a menu(point) a folder, a blue box or a grey sphere?
Along the same lines, moving menupoints amd articles up/down should use the same metaphor for moving.

Third, reconsider your rights. What good is the right of cutting a menupoint if you can't paste it somewhere?

Fourth; don't just grab icons. Make them. Even if you find a pretty complete, well fitting set of icons, it's not gonna be a 100% match. Copy and edit, or make additional icons from scratch. This way you can get clear and consistent iconography.

Comment: The good of the right of cutting vs the right of pasting is that a rightgroup can be bound to a menupoint. Here it goes complicated and i keepd that back. I really like the rearrange-hint. I never did custom icons before.